# Within phytools, what distribution does the pbtree function use to simulate a phylogeny?

Tags: simulation, phylogeny

I have seen the function pbtree (within R package phytools) be used to simulate phylogeny. How does this actually work?

I'm particularly interested in the model distributions used to pick the time and branch which splits occur upon.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The function provides a number of options for simulating trees, which are explained in the help page for the function (check `?pbtree`).

You can simulate trees using either a pure-birth (i.e., speciation with no extinction) or a birth-death model (i.e., both speciation and extinction occur). If the death rate argument is set to `d = 0`, it is a pure-birth model. If the death rate is greater than 0, it is a birth-death model.

You can simulate the trees using continuous or discrete time by setting the `type` argument. If it is continuous time, then the birth and/or death times for each branch are drawn from an exponential distribution. If it is discrete time, then the birth and/or death times are drawn from a geometric distribution.

You can simulate trees until they reach a certain time `t`, or until they reach a certain number of taxa `n`. Or you can specify BOTH `t` and `n`, in which case the function attempts to find a tree that satisfies both conditions, but sometimes this doesn't work if you choose difficult values for `t` and `n`, in which case the function gives up after a certain number of tries specified by `max.count`.